# AsyncTask error in update ListView process

Tags: java, android

How can i retrieve data from my db and push it to my listview ?
i want use an asynctask for this.

I have used this code but my app crached every time when i run this.
idk why because when i push data to my db then it works fine. But when i retrieve then i get errors.

```
public class GetAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,ArrayList<Task>,String> {

private Context context;
private ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<Task> tasks;

public GetAsync(Context context,ListView listview) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listView = listview;
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    TaskDbHelper db = new TaskDbHelper(context);
    tasks.addAll(db.getTasks());
    return "werkt";
}



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    tasks = (ArrayAdapter<Task>) listView.getAdapter();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
```

}

```
    lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    new GetAsync(this,lvItems).execute();
```

Comment: Can your provide the stack trace of the exception that caused the crash?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public class GetAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,ArrayList<Task>,List<Task>> {

    private Context context;
    private ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<Task> tasks;

    public GetAsync(Context context, ListView listview) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listView = listview;
    }


    @Override
    protected List<Task> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        TaskDbHelper db = new TaskDbHelper()
        return db.getTasks();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        tasks = (ArrayAdapter<Task>) listView.getAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Task> tasks) {
        tasks.addAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

It's because you are not on the UI thread whilst modifying the view. So you want to update the adapter in `onPostExecute` as that runs on the thread that started the AsyncTask (which I'm assuming is the UI thread)

Comment: He is not updating the UI if I am right. He is just adding them to the list. I may be wrong and that also fires the UI to update, but not that I know

Comment: It could call `notifyDataSetChanged` https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L217 which would need to be on the UI thread

Comment: yep. Also wanted to answer for moving to UI thread, but I guess it is the answer

Comment: So what is result is null after calling `db.getTasks();` ? You should return the list, with the AsyncTask I.e. `<Void, Void, ArrayList<Task>> ` - not just return a String that serves no purpose.

Comment: with this code i have no errors but my listview is empty. with the the db connectie i get a list and that list i want get in my listview on my mainactivity

Comment: there's some other problem beyond the code that you have posted then